# In a parent class, should I make class properties private, forcing inheritors to use getters/setters?

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation

For example, with a parent like this:

```
class Music {
  private $timbre;   // This?
  protected $timbre; // Or this?

  public function getTimbre(){
    return $this->timbre;
  }
}
```

In an inheriting child, is it OK from an OO point of view to access the member variable directly, or best to use the getters/setters?

```
class PostPunk extends Music {
  public function doSomethingTimbreRelated(){
    $punk_timbre = $this->getTimbre(); // This?
    $punk_timbre = $this->timbre;      // Or this?

    // ... do something ...
  }
}
```

I've read that keeping member variables private is better for encapsulation, but does that really matter in an inheritance hierarchy?

And I realize this is very trivial, but I sort of waffle back and forth to doing it both ways, so I'd like to settle in on one way

Comment: getters and setters are mostly for your public clients/consumers. When you need to access properties from class itself that is absolutely ok to access them directly through `$this->timbre`

Comment: @Alex I don't think it absolutely ok to access parent properties directly. You might have properties that are not supposed to change (e.g. a property holding a database object). In such a case, I set the visibility to protected.

Comment: @dnFer if property set as `protected` that means that parent has no objections for children to access them, if property set as `private` - that will not allow by php itself. Check please: https://ideone.com/YQBhGi

Comment: Yes... I mean private ofcourse. My bad. but can't edit my comment anymore. But my point is, sometimes you do want getters/setters and sometimes you don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, now I understand that using getters/setters promotes **loose coupling** to the parent object, via **encapsulation**.

In a small project with few developers and simple classes, the benefits of this are not obvious.

However, imagine a large project with many inheriting classes, as well as external classes consuming getters/setters.

If, down the road, you need to modify or add some business logic to the value returned by the getter, you will have to rewire all of the inheritors to use the getters VS accessing the properties directly.

Same goes for the setter - perhaps you decide to add some data sanitization/validation. Directly accessing the properties will bypass these future improvements.

*Analogy: Rather than letting your kid have free access to your purse/wallet, you are forcing her to ask you for money, then you decide what and how much to give her.*